# winverify trust results 2148204800 only in windows server 2012 r2 standard VM

Tags: c#, digital-signature

We are doing the MSI validation using below code.

```
WinTrustData wtd = new WinTrustData(fileName);
Guid guidAction = new Guid(WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2);
WinVerifyTrustResult result = NativeMethods.WinVerifyTrust(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, guidAction, wtd);
bool ret = (result == WinVerifyTrustResult.Success);
```

The MSI file is having proper digital sign and it is working fine in all the OS versions except windows server 2012 R2 standard.
Ay suggestions or solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 2148204800 == 0x800B0100 == TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE, "The app package is unsigned".

Comment: We have identified that the root certificate was disabled in the certificate store and after enabling the particular root certificate of the msi file, the issue got resolved, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have identified that the root certificate was disabled in the certificate store and after enabling the particular root certificate of the msi file, the issue got resolved, Thank you